# Duplicate Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I was working in SharePoint powerShell and ran the command [Get-SPSite -Limit All] and I get the list of sites as expected, however, One Site shows up twice (see example below);

```
//mysite
//mysite/personal/user1
//misite/personal/user2
//teamsite
//teamsite
//teamsite/dept/it
//teamsite/dept/finance
//teamsite/dept/spgov
```

Should I be seeing teamsite twice?

If Not, how do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Command that you provided returns list of all sites from ALL WebApplications.
Please, make sure that there is no another site with url "/teamsite" on any another WebApplication.

Comment: I have the same problem, where Get-SPSite returns three instances of the same SPSite site collection, ID's and URL's exactly the same.

Comment: Could you provide full command's string?

Comment: Get-SPWebApplication http://contoso.com | Get-SPSite | ft Url,Id

Answer (score 0):

To remedy the duplicated site collection issue, you can try dismounting the content database and re-mounting it.

you can get the name of the content database with:

```
$s = get-spsite http://teamsite
$s.ContentDatabase
$name = $s.ContentDatabase.Name

Dismount-SPContentDatabase $s.ContentDatabase

Mount-SPContentDatabase -webapplication http://teamsite -name $name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this today and found another way to do this is to modify the command to be:

```
Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet | Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | select -Unique
```

The -Limit ALL isn't required, but you will want to use that if you have more than 20 Site Collections, the | select -Unique is what will acutally remove the duplicate URL in the list.