# Duplicate site collection with Get-SPSite

Tags: 2013, powershell, site-collection

I have the same problem as this question ([Duplicate Site Collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65657/duplicate-site-collection)) but unfortunately dismounting and re-mounting the database did not solve my problem.

Just to clarify, if I run Get-SPSite, the root site collection for the web application is listed twice. Both entries have the same Id and the same web application.

```
Get-SPSite

<guid1>  http://site1   <web app 1>    <DB1>
<guid1>  http://site1   <web app 1>    <DB1>
... other sites in other databases
```

Get-SPSite with the ContentDatabase parameter specified only returns 1 site.

```
Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase DB1

http://site1
```

Also, if I get the database based on the site parameter, I get one database:

```
Get-SPContentDatabase -Site http://site1

Id                ...
Name              DB1...
WebApplication    ...
Server            ...
CurrentSiteCount  1
```

Obviously I've changed site and DB names and omitted irrelevant details but hopefully you get the idea. If there is anything specific you want me to include, I can get it.

I think I might have to try moving the site to another database but am hoping to avoid that. It isn't a huge issue because everything seems to be working fine elsewhere. I just don't want it to cause any issues later.

Does anyone have any other suggestions for clearing this up?

**Update:**

Running `Get-SPProduct -Local` returns the following:

```
ProductName                       Required   Missing              Servers
-----------                       --------   -------              -------
Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013  True                            {}
```

Also, checked the SiteMap table as recommended by @TrevorSeward and it only returns one site, as expected.

I even tried running proc_getSiteNames on the config DB just like the Get-SPSite cmdlet does. It didn't return any duplicate sites. Unfortunately I get a bit lost in that code so maybe didn't do it right.

It seems I can get the duplicate site to appear also by displaying the SPWebApplication.Sites property in PowerShell.

Comment: run this command to refresh the site collection count in config db....get-spproduct -local. after that share the result.

Comment: Can you also try "USE [ConfigDbName]; SELECT * FROM SiteMap WITH (NoLock) WHERE Path = '/' AND ApplicationID = '<SPWebApplication.Id>'". I'm making the assumption that your Site Collection is a root path ("/"), so make adjustments as necessary (e.g. '/sites/mysite').